# How to measure round trip time with gstreamer webrtcbin?

Tags: gstreamer

I am developing a cloud rendering service and am considering using gstreamer (webrtcbin).
The user's input is processed by an app running on a server and the video is sent to the user.
Therefore, I would like to measure the Round Trip time accurately to some extent.Is there any method?

I'm considering Insertable Streams (or Encoded Transform) as a means of instrumentation, can gstreamer (webrtcbin) achieve the equivalent of Insertable Streams (or Encoded Transform)?

Comment: Round-trip time is already part of the rtp stats available on the browser. You could send that to the server via a datachannle. I think the stats in webrtcbin are still somewhat limited, at least in 1.16.

Comment: thank you. I tried to see if I could use statistical information, but it didn't seem to work, so I wondered if I could measure it by adding metadata to the frame data.